# How do I find an element nested in I-frames?

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I wish to test the body of an email.

It uses a FCK editor sitting 3 i-frames deep.

```
<...name="fancybox-frame"...>
    <iframe>
        <iframe>
             <body>H E R E  I S  W H A T   I   W A N T  T O   A C C E S S</body>
        </iframe>
    </iframe>
</[fancybox-frame]>
```

Aside from the fun with ambiguity, how do I use within-frame multiple times.

If i use this...

```
within_frame('fancybox-frame') do
fill_in('frm_subject', :with => eventname + ' email')
within_frame('iframe[id="frm_message___Frame"]') do
  within_frame('iframe') do
    fill_in('body', :with => 'Event email for ' + now.to_s)
  end
end
```

end

I get this...

```
      switchFrame execution failed;
   INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51 (Selenium::WebDriver::Erro
r::WebDriverError)
  ./features/step_definitions/RCST08_steps.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in <to
p (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/RCST08_steps.rb:94:in `/^select a message to s
end\.$/'
  features\RCST08.feature:26:in `And select a message to send.'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have the iframe id that is nested 2 degrees deep? If yes switch to it and then perform your actions

Answer (score 2):

Selenium can't address anything inside a frame (<IFRAME> or <FRAME>) until you "switch" to it.  In the Ruby bindings, that's what `within_frame(...) do ... end` does.  You seem to be one frame outside of where you want to be.  You need something more like this:

```
within_frame('fancybox-frame') do
  fill_in('frm_subject', :with => eventname + ' email')
  within_frame('iframe[id="frm_message___Frame"]') do
    within_frame('...name of outer iframe...') do
      within_frame('...name of inner iframe...') do
        fill_in('body', :with => 'Event email for ' + now.to_s)
      end
    end
  end
end
```